# Is there a Pandas function to count events between timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

My data has few 100k of rows and the following columns:

1. `Time` (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff),
2. `ID` (string),
3. `Group1`(int32),
4. `Group2` (int32).

I would like to count how many events came from the same `Group1` and `Group2` prior to each event, in a time window of 5 minutes.
For example:

```
ID              Time                      Group1    Group2
61ED2269CCAC    2020-07-27 00:01:05.781   1234      100123
61C2DC4E96FA    2020-07-27 00:01:17.279   1234      100123
FAD0839C1A95    2020-07-27 00:02:38.112   1234      100124
A2750A7B6C24    2020-07-27 00:16:50.592   4321      100123
03F5DF150A3C    2020-07-27 00:17:00.246   4321      100124
```

How many events came after `Timestamp('2020-07-26 23:56:17.279000')` (5 minutes before the second event) and belong to groups `Group1` and `Group2`? So the second event would have a counter of 1 in this example. The rest will have a counter of 0 as their groups are unique.

Each event should have a counter indicating how many events came before it from the same groups.

I tried sorting the data by the groups and by `Time`, then running a nested-loop, one running on all events and one running from the start up to the current event index. After few 1000 rows, the process slows down significantly, rendering this option non-feasible.
I was wondering if there is any other elegant and efficient way of doing this.

EDIT:
I was able to do this with one for-loop instead of a nested one. For each loop I took the Time and the groups and sliced the Dataframe to include the events in the groups and in the desired time frame, and then summed the number of events:

```
for i in tqdm(range(len(df))):
   time_stamp = df.loc[i, 'Time']
   group1 = df.loc[i, 'Group1']
   group2 = df.loc[i, 'Group2']
   sub_df = df[df['Time'] + timedelta(minutes=-5) > time_stamp]
   sub_df = sub_df[sub_df['Time'] < time_stamp]
   sub_df = sub_df[sub_df['Group1'] == group1]
   sub_df = sub_df[sub_df['Group2'] == group2]
   df.loc[i, 'prior_events'] = sub_df.size
```

Still, tqdm shows 18 iteration per second, which is not that great for 100k rows.

Comment: Please include [minimal-reproducible-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4985099)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a more instructive result, I extended your data sample:

```
              ID                    Time  Group1  Group2
0   61ED2269CCAC 2020-07-27 00:01:05.781    1234  100123
1   61C2DC4E96FA 2020-07-27 00:01:17.279    1234  100123
2   FAD0839C1A95 2020-07-27 00:02:38.112    1234  100124
3   FAD0839C1A95 2020-07-27 00:05:38.000    1234  100123
4   FAD0839C1A95 2020-07-27 00:06:39.000    1234  100123
5   A2750A7B6C24 2020-07-27 00:16:50.592    4321  100123
6   03F5DF150A3C 2020-07-27 00:17:00.246    4321  100124
7   03F5DF150A3C 2020-07-27 00:18:00.000    4321  100124
8   03F5DF150A3C 2020-07-27 00:20:00.000    4321  100124
9   03F5DF150A3C 2020-07-27 00:22:00.000    4321  100124
10  03F5DF150A3C 2020-07-27 00:23:00.000    4321  100124
```

Assuming that *Time* column is of *datetime* type and its values are unique,
you can generate the result (*Count* column) as follows:

```
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
df['Count'] = (df.groupby(['Group1', 'Group2'], as_index=False)\
    .Group1.rolling(window='5T', closed='both').count() - 1).astype(int)\
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
                      Time            ID  Group1  Group2  Count
0  2020-07-27 00:01:05.781  61ED2269CCAC    1234  100123      0
1  2020-07-27 00:01:17.279  61C2DC4E96FA    1234  100123      1
2  2020-07-27 00:02:38.112  FAD0839C1A95    1234  100124      0
3  2020-07-27 00:05:38.000  FAD0839C1A95    1234  100123      2
4  2020-07-27 00:06:39.000  FAD0839C1A95    1234  100123      1
5  2020-07-27 00:16:50.592  A2750A7B6C24    4321  100123      0
6  2020-07-27 00:17:00.246  03F5DF150A3C    4321  100124      0
7  2020-07-27 00:18:00.000  03F5DF150A3C    4321  100124      1
8  2020-07-27 00:20:00.000  03F5DF150A3C    4321  100124      2
9  2020-07-27 00:22:00.000  03F5DF150A3C    4321  100124      3
10 2020-07-27 00:23:00.000  03F5DF150A3C    4321  100124      3
```

Note the last row. Is has *Count* == **3**, including the event just
5 minutes before.
If you want this event **not** to be counted, drop *closed='both'*
parameter.

## Edit following the comment as of 14:49Z

Apparently your data have repeating *Time* values, even within a group
of rows with same *Group1* / *Group2*.

To cope with this, take another approach:

1. Define a function generating counts:

   ```
    def Counts(grp):
        vc = grp.Time.value_counts().sort_index()
        cnt = (vc.rolling(window='5T', closed='both').sum()).astype(int) - vc
        s = pd.Series(cnt, index=grp.Time)
        return pd.Series(s.values, index=grp.index)
   ```
2. Apply it:

   ```
    df['Counts'] = df.groupby(['Group1', 'Group2'], as_index=False)\
        .apply(Counts).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
   ```

This code is based on assumption that your source DataFrame is ordered
by *Time*.

I tested the above code on a data sample with an added row with repeated
*Time* from the previous row.

The result is:

```
              ID                    Time  Group1  Group2  Counts
0   61ED2269CCAC 2020-07-27 00:01:05.781    1234  100123       0
1   61C2DC4E96FA 2020-07-27 00:01:17.279    1234  100123       1
2   FAD0839C1A95 2020-07-27 00:02:38.112    1234  100124       0
3   FAD0839C1A95 2020-07-27 00:05:38.000    1234  100123       2
4   FAD0839C1A95 2020-07-27 00:06:39.000    1234  100123       1
5   A2750A7B6C24 2020-07-27 00:16:50.592    4321  100123       0
6   03F5DF150A3C 2020-07-27 00:17:00.246    4321  100124       0
7   03F5DF150A3C 2020-07-27 00:18:00.000    4321  100124       1
8   03F5DF150A3C 2020-07-27 00:20:00.000    4321  100124       2
9   03F5DF150A3C 2020-07-27 00:22:00.000    4321  100124       3
10  03F5DF150A3C 2020-07-27 00:23:00.000    4321  100124       3
11  03F5DF150BBB 2020-07-27 00:23:00.000    4321  100124       3
```

Comment: I like this direction of rolling. I forgot to mention the uniqueness of the ID columns. As in my example, an ID can appear only once. Also, I get this ValueError: window must be an integer. If I change the window to 5 instead of '5T', I lose the ID granularity. I don't see how you get the ID back if it is not in the columns you are referring

Comment: Error message *window must be an integer* occurs if the index is of type
other than *datetime*. Probably you have *Time* column as **string**.
Change it to *datetime* and my code should work without errors.

Comment: I now get ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! Does that mean I have non-unique Time values?